# Pick color or symbol of marker in Plotly r on a group by condition

Tags: r, plotly, scatter-plot, r-plotly

```
+----+------+-------+
| Id | Time | Value |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 | A    |     1 |
|  2 | B    |    10 |
|  2 | C    |     3 |
|  2 | D    |     6 |
|  3 | E    |     2 |
|  4 | F    |     9 |
|  4 | G    |     4 |
|  4 | H    |    17 |
+----+------+-------+
```

I have data like above (simplified). I have drawn this using a scatter plot using plot-ly with Id as the X axis and value as the Y axis. Now based on the time column, I want the most recent entry for the Id field to have a specific shape/symbol. How can I do this using plot-ly and r?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a column to flag the last entry, then use that column as an aesthetic .

For example, in `ggplot`:

```
df %>%
    group_by(Id) %>%
    mutate(
        rowNo = 1:n(),
        isLast = factor(ifelse(rowNo == n(), 1, 0))) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Id, y = Value, shape = isLast)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

And similarly for `plot_ly`.

```
df %>%
    group_by(Id) %>%
    mutate(
        rowNo = 1:n(),
        isLast = factor(ifelse(rowNo == n(), 1, 0))) %>%
    plot_ly(x = ~Id, y = ~Value, symbol = ~isLast)
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Id  Time Value
1 A  1
2 B 10
2 C  3
2 D  6
3 E  2
4 F  9
4 G  4
4 H 17", header = T)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see the chart has only shaped the last value in the dataset. I want to do this per Id value i.e. Every ID should have at least one shaped marker

Comment: @user1337323 I have updated my answer, please take a look. We can use `group_by` to flag the last entry per `Id`.